# How to make multiple threads run parallally such that execution of threads takes place one after the other

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I am trying to acheive parallal thread execution. for example

> t1, t2, and t3 are three threads , each performing a task to print
>   multiplication table. I want to execute them in a sequence

```
--------------------------------
|   t1    |    t2    |    t3   | 
--------------------------------
|   2     |     3    |     4   |
|   4     |     6    |     8   |
|   6     |     9    |    12   |
|   ..    |    ..    |   ..    |
|------------------------------|
```

execution sequence : t1--> t2--> t3 --> t1

so far, i am able to create three thread that does task independently

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SynchronizationExample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);   
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
            es.execute(new Task(i));
        }
        es.shutdown();

        while(!es.isTerminated()){

        }
        System.out.println("finished all task");
    }
}
```

Task class

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    private int i; 
    public Task(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "Start counter = " + i);
        processMessage();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "End counter");
    }

    public void processMessage(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

output :

```
pool-1-thread-1Start counter = 1
pool-1-thread-3Start counter = 3
pool-1-thread-2Start counter = 2
pool-1-thread-1End counter
pool-1-thread-1Start counter = 4
pool-1-thread-3End counter
pool-1-thread-3Start counter = 5
pool-1-thread-2End counter
pool-1-thread-2Start counter = 6
pool-1-thread-1End counter
pool-1-thread-1Start counter = 7
pool-1-thread-3End counter
pool-1-thread-3Start counter = 8
pool-1-thread-2End counter
pool-1-thread-2Start counter = 9
pool-1-thread-1End counter
pool-1-thread-1Start counter = 10
pool-1-thread-3End counter
pool-1-thread-2End counter
pool-1-thread-1End counter
finished all task
```

Comment: Why not just use a single thread then?

Comment: Please explain the reason you want to print in different threads if you want them to work sequencially.

Comment: 'Parallel ... one after the other' is a contradiction in terms. If you want sequential execution, don't use threads.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the reply. Here by Parallel i meant, running all 3 threads separately  in such a way that thread 't1' starts its first iteration and wait for  t2 to complete their first iteration and upon the third thread 't2' has finished its first iteration then thread 't3' starts its first iteration. Once t3 is done its first iteration, thread t1 should resumes its second iteration. and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to acheive parallal thread execution. for example t1, t2, and t3 are three threads , each performing a task to print multiplication table. **I want to execute them in a sequence.**

That is a contradiction in terms.

You can do things in parallel or in sequence, but you cannot do both at the same time.  (It is like running and riding a bicycle at the same time!)

---

As @Thilo states, the simple, practical (and best) solution is not to do this with multiple threads.  Just use one thread and a `for` loop.

If you are intent on doing this using multiple threads, then you need the threads to synchronize.  (That is what appears to be the problem with your current code.  You have no synchronization ... just three "free running" threads and `sleep()` calls.  That approach is never going to be reliable.)

For instance,

- thread 1 prints a line, tells thread 2 - "your turn", and waits for its turn
- thread 2 prints a line, tells thread 3 - "your turn", and waits for its turn
- thread 3 prints a line, tells thread 1 - "your turn", and waits for its turn
- and so on

until you get to the end.  (You will need to do something special then ...)

This notification could take the form of 3 separate "channels" (primitive mutexes, latches, semaphores, queues, whatever) for each three pairs of threads, or a single "channel" where each thread wait for its turn.

(There are other ways to solve this too ... but we don't need to go into that here.)